# How do i load an entire word into a register so i can test my functions in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I am trying to test my string length function in mips. I want to test it out with a word like "happy" or anthing like that..... but i do not know how to do this. It would be great to also learn how to print it out to the screen.

This is my code:

```
.globl StringLength

StringLength:
li $t0,0

StringLengthLoop:
lb $t1,0($a0)
beq $t1,$zero, StringLengthExit
add $a0,$a0,1
add $t0,$t0,1
j StringLengthLoop

StringLengthExit:
move $v0, $t0
jr $ra
```

Answer (score 1):

To print to the console you will have utilize one of many [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) available on your system. (The exact system call values depend on your system/emulator.)

A string can be placed in the data segment of your executable with a label which can be used to get the address of the start of the string. ".ascii" means a non-null terminated string while ".asciiz" means a null-terminated string.

Here is a simple example on how to print a string and an integer value:

```
        .data
str:    .asciiz "This is a string\n"  # a null-terminated string to be printed.
        .align 2                      # make sure it's aligned to word boundary
int:    .word 1234                    # some number

        .text
        .global main
main:
        la    $a0, str        # load the address of the start of our string
        li    $v0, 4          # syscall 4 usually means print string
        syscall

        la    $t0, int        # the address of our number
        lw    $a0, 0($t0)     # get our number
        li    $v0, 1          # syscall 1 usually means print int
        syscall

        li    $v0, 10         # syscall 10 usually means exit
        syscall               # exit.
```

A more practical example:

If I was to utilize your function, it would look something like this: (Assuming it follows the standard calling convention of arguments in $aN and return value in $vN. Which indeed it does.)

```
        .data
str:    .asciiz "This is an example"

        .text
        .global main
main:
        la    $a0, str        # first argument, a pointer to the string
        jal   StringLength    # call StringLength(str)

        # print the length
        add   $a0, $zero, $v0
        li    $v0, 1
        syscall

        li    $v0, 10
        syscall               # exit
```

Most emulators use the same system calls. [Here is a list of system calls for the MARS simulator](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html).

Final Note: If you plan on loading a value using the lw instruction, make sure you tell the assembler to align it to a word boundary (.align 2) as I did with the first example.